# How do I add storage with cloud templating?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation template to spin up an EC2 instance.

```
Parameters:
  InstanceType:
    Type: String
    Description: Instance type for RStudio. Default is t2.micro.
    AllowedValues:
      - t2.micro
      - t2.small
      - t2.medium
      - t2.large
    ConstraintDescription: 'Valid instance type in the t2 family'
    Default: t2.micro
  ImageId:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Image::Id'
    Description: >-
      Amazon Linux Image ID. Default is for 2017.03.01 (HVM). N.B. 
    Default: ami-4fffc834
```

When I spin up the instance manually, there is an option to add storage. It defaults to 8gb and I'd like to do 16gb instead.

I looked for the syntax to add storage with CloudFormation. What is the syntax to set a volume size other than the default?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify size in the BlockDeviceMappings section of you EC2 CloudFormation Template. Here you can specify VolumeType, IOPS, Termination Actions and VolumeSize.

```
MyEC2Instance: 
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  Properties: 
    ImageId: "ami-79fd7eee"
    KeyName: "testkey"
    BlockDeviceMappings: 
    - DeviceName: "/dev/sdm"
      Ebs: 
        VolumeType: "io1"
        Iops: "200"
        DeleteOnTermination: "false"
        VolumeSize: "20"
    - DeviceName: "/dev/sdk"
      NoDevice: {}
```

You can read more here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html